# SharePoint 2019 - Adding Custom Response Header Is Not Working

Tags: iis, sharepoint, iis-10, windows-server-2019, sharepoint-2019

I'm trying to add a custom response header to a SharePoint 2019 site but the response returning from the server is not showing this header, any idea why?

- SharePoint version: 2019 Standard
- OS: Windows Server 2019 Standard
- IIS version: 10.0.17763.1

I tested using a custom website on the same server and the response header is working fine which means IIS is fine so I doubt it is not showing because of SharePoint itself.

Comment: Read FRT to learn how the header is being applied (or not applied), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis From there you should know what solution might be.

Answer (score 0):

What about add custom response header with URL rewrite outbound rule?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module

```
       <rule name="add header">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_MyHeader" pattern="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="value" />
        </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please do the same in IIS. So the rule will be automatically set in the config file. put the same condition in IIS. Maybe it will work. before creating the new one , please remove the existing rule in config file then create a new one through IIS.